What arrows to use in component diagrams to show relations between JPMS layers?
JPMS supports multiple layers. For example boot layer and its two child layers.
And I need to show these layers on UML diagram. For this I selected component diagram where every layer is a component. And my question is what arrows I should use to show relations. I think about dependency arrows:

but I am not sure. Could anyone say what arrows should be used in this case?

I'm not a Java expert but I wondered: is the layer  a component (i.e. there are dependencies and interfaces between layers) or is it a deployment artifact, the dependencies being in reality between modules "packaged" in  layers that are just a packaging of modules for better runtime deployment?

@Christophe From javadoc A layer is created from a graph of modules in a Configuration and a function that maps each module to a ClassLoader. Creating a layer informs the Java virtual machine about the classes that may be loaded from the modules so that the Java virtual machine knows which module that each class is a member of.. As I know there are no dependencies between layers (Layer methods: parents(), modules()) , only between modules (Module methods: addExports(...), addReads(...), addOpens(...)).

If module M1 in layer L1 depends on module M2 in layer L2, then layer L1 depends on layer L2.

Your assumption is correct: dependency arrows should be used.
The direction of a dependency arrow is from the dependent component to the component on which it depends. In this case, Child 1 and Child 2 require Boot layer to be present.
To clarify the relationship even more, you could attach stereotype «use» to both arrows. The UML 2.5.1 specification, section 7.4.4 says: "A Usage is shown as a Dependency with a «use» keyword attached to it."
